# VBA to search a reference sheet, return error when it doesn't exist

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets, one is a report of ticket numbers and the other is a reference for possible alternative numbers. Here's what I want to do:

- grab value from report
- search for it in the reference sheet
- if it exists in the reference sheet, return the adjacent column value
- if it doesn't exist, skip it and look at the next value in the report

I can easily do this with a `vlookup` function in the sheet itself, but there are a lot of rows and I'm trying to speed it up with VBA.

So far I've tried using `application.vlookup` first, then combined "Find" & "Offset" methods to grab what I want. Both work fine as long as the value from the report exists in the search range of my reference sheet. If it doesn't, I get hit with an error.

I don't know what else to try. This is what I have right now using "Find" & "Offset", I deleted the code using `application.vlookup`:

```
    Function ticket_lookup(NS35 As Long) As Long 
    Dim rngholder As Range
    Set rngholder = Worksheets("Ticket_No").Range("A1")
    Dim holder As Long
    Dim rw As Integer

    rw = Worksheets("Ticket_No").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

    rngholder = Worksheets("Ticket_No").Range("A2:B" & rw).Find(NS35, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)

    If Not rngholder Is Nothing Then
        holder = rngholder.Cells(rw, "A").Offset(, 1).Value
```

I've got some error handling below this for certain values that I've recycled from somewhere else and know works. NS35 is the value passed from the report sheet. I checked rngholder for Nothing because I thought "Find" was supposed to return nothing if it couldn't find the value.

Comment: `rw = Worksheets("Ticket_No").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row` doesn't work very well if there are blank cells in the middle of the data. It is better to use `rw = Worksheets("Ticket_No").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row`. Also, why use `Integer` when you know about `Long`? It just risks overflow for no gain.

Comment: Missing `Set`: `Set rngholder = ...`

Comment: @JohnColeman there are no blanks in the data set. And I'm using a small sample right now. I tend to work by finding a solution first, then fine tuning it later.

Comment: @BigBen I did set rngholder, just after I declared it as a range. Are you saying to set rngholder explicitly as "..."?

Comment: Your code snippet is missing a `Set` before `rngholder = Worksheets("Ticket_No").Range("A2:B" & rw)`. Get rid of `Set rngholder = Worksheets("Ticket_No").Range("A1")`.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks, that works. Just to be clear, my mistake was trying to treat an object like a variable, correct? Because I declared rngholder as Range, it's an object and must be set when on the left side of  =, yes? Creating objects is still new to me.

Comment: If you don't use `Set`, then you're implicitly doing `rngholder.Value = ...`.